# Ruby on rail multiple product possibility on invoice table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have by the moment 4 tables on my web-market.

```
Table User: Username + password + email.
Table Serie: Serie name + price + description
Table Season: Season name + price + description + fk(Serie)   //Each season belongs to a serie 
Table Chapter: Chapter name + price + description + fk(Season)   //Each chapter belongs to a season
```

The user would be able to buy either series seasons and chapters. The main idea is the following:

```
Table invoice: fk(user)   //User have multiple invoices
Table invoice_line: fk(invoice), fk(serie|season|chapter)   //Each invoice contains multiple products
```

How can I represent that serie|season|chapter relation easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) from Active Record.

It can be represented like this:

```
class InvoiceLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :containable, polymorphic: true
end
```

With this definition you should have table like this:

```
create_table :invoice_lines do |t|
  t.references :invoice,
  t.references :containable, polymorphic: true
end
```

`t.references :containable, polymorphic: true` will create both integer containable_id and string containable_type columns.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and show me how will be Invoice, Serie, Season and Chapter tables?